# How can I set an AppleScript to run when a given file is modified?

Tags: applescript

I know that applescripts can be set to run as folder actions, but is there a way to get them to run as *file* actions? Yes, I know I can work around this by just making a new folder, putting the script in it, and running as a folder action, but I want to know if this can be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cross-posted this question to [Apple's Applescript discussion board](https://discussions.apple.com/message/13182902#13182902), and a few users there gave some solutions that use only system resources, with no third-party applications. Follow the link to see the answers.

Basically you need to use `launchd` to watch a file and launch a script when the file changes. Then you'd need to craft a `.plist` that describes the script to run and the file(s) or directories to watch.

Comment: I should have thought of that.  Launchd is a great way to do this.  I'd advise running Lingon which makes managing Launchd stuff much easier.  I *think* it's available at the App Store although clearly it violates the guidelines.  (I got it back when it was free)  Be aware that the problem with Launchd is it'll attempt to run the Applescript whether anyone is logged in or not.  But without someone logged in you'll get weird errors.

Comment: Unfortunately the link is broken. That's why we post the solution rather than just the link.

Comment: @andreherculano - updated the answer to include a working link. I don't have time to modify the answer now, but if you want to edit it in, go ahead.

Comment: Thank you @eykanal I copied the accepted answer from the link into your answer. Hope it helps someone :)

Answer (score 0):

There's no simple built in way to do this.  However there's lots of ways to set up an Applescript to run.  However in general you'll have to do some non-Applescript coding.

Check out the info in this hint and OSXHints:

http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20060817044149264

They have a Python script demonstrating using fsevents.so to monitor file changes.  You would then just modify the Python to call your Applescript (or simply use Appscript to do the scripting from within Python).

Alternatively you can just have a program check a file at a particular interval and then run if the file changes.  This hint describes that in Perl:

http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20031001073403810

Answer (score -1):

I found a way to do this that works.

Shell script:

```
find watchedfilepath -mtime -1 -exec cp {} watchedfolderpath ';'
```

Create a Calendar Event in Automator to run this shell script which will check the file. If it has been modified in the last 24 hours, then it will be copied to the watched folder. Then create an action in Automator to move it to trash (otherwise the next time the shell script runs it won't work).

Set up a Folder Action on the watched folder to watch for an added new item and then it will let you know. I have created a script to send me an email and put that in the Folder Actions folder in Library/Scripts. It works like a treat.

Answer (score -1):

This is an old question, but the Apple Automator tool in MacOS does ***exactly*** this. You can set it to watch a folder and execute an Applescript, Shell Script, etc.

Comment: Note that a folder action is not triggered when a file is modified.